# My Sharepoint site down. Leaving Monitored Scope

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, logs

So my sharepoint site is down. Checked the logs and there's nothing. The only log I could find is Leaving Monitored Scope (Request...) Execution Time=0.999334

What seems to be the issue with this log?

Comment: you need to turn logging on, do that under central admin. also what do you mean its down? when you go to the page what do you see, what number does it give you? 500, 501, 503, 404, 403?

Comment: No it doesn't. it only says this page can't be displayed. @aliJafer

Comment: interesting. is this http or https? can you show a full screendump of the page?

Comment: its https. So the issue with me was it was only one site from about 10 site collection I've that was not working. After a bit of workaround and recreating the site again. I was able to browse the site but only in firefox, not chrome and IE. so I configured keberos to the server. It's a weird fix cause it's just this one site. Still need to look in to it but for now site is up :)

Answer (score 0):

When a SharePoint site goes down, these are the steps I usually take/look at:

- Can other users log into the site?
- Reboot the server
- Can I log into the server?
- Can I open the site from the server?
- Can I access Central Admin from the server?
- Are there any SharePoint services set to Automatic but not running? (Timer, Administration)
- Is the SQL Database service running?

One of the above things usually ends up being the culprit otherwise there's typically bigger issues at play (network issues, server issues, etc.)